# Is there any significant difference between 5-56 and WD-40?

Tags: rust-removal

In Sweden, we mainly use 5-56 for "everything", but in the U.S. WD-40 seems to be the thing.

Both seem to penetrate deeply, dissolve rust and do some slight lubrication.

Just curious to the differences, if any any.

Comment: You can add Phosphoric Acid (or Cola) to help the WD-40 along (or to shine your rusty chrome!)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

They are competing products that are both advertised to do the same five things ([WD-40](http://www.wd40.com/faqs/#a97), [CRC 5-56](http://www.crcind.com/wwwcrc/tds/TCA3%205-56.PDF)). It's not clear that one is any better than the other.

Comment: How about PB-Blaster? Anybody use it?

Answer (score 0):

[PB Blaster](http://www.pbblaster.com/) is truly a superior penetrant to loosen frozen threaded fasteners.

[image: PB Blaster]

No comparison to WD-40 or CRC 5-56

Comment: Could you describe how and why it works better?

Comment: Hey, just to mention this link is broken now :)